# UI component vs stylesheet - Vue 3 best practice

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Opinions on best practice for the two following styling methods when no additional HTML is needed by the component?

**Slot method**

```html
<template>
  <div class="ui-component">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.ui-component { padding: 10px; };
:slotted(.child-class){ color: red }
</style>
```

Which is then used like this:

```html
<template>
  <UiComponent>
    <div class="child-class">Style me</div>
  </UiComponent>
</template>
```

**Versus a separate stylesheet method**

```css
/* ui-component.css */
.ui-component { padding: 10px; };
.ui-component .child-class { color: red; }
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="ui-component">
    <div class="child-class">Style me</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

When there is no functionality or extra HTML required by the parent component, I'm inclined to just create an external class and use option 2, but interested to hear opinions as I can't see this discussed anywhere when digging online.

Comment: The choice is based on their specific traits. You need a stylesheet when you need to detach from comp scopes, like a design system with multiple themes and less duplicated style code. On the other hand, the scopes are beneficial when it's an embedded widget on a third-party page that doesn't have theme constraints